# How to stop an HTTP connection, assuming lost connection?

Tags: java, android

The following code is from the Facebook Android SDK, and is used for all the interactions with Facebook.  I'm using it to search and/or post to Facebook in a service that's holding a wakelock.  So if the phone somehow loses Internet connectivity, I want the service to give up and terminate to avoid wasting battery.

What I don't understand is how you would go about interrupting something like this, because the problem might happen at any point within this method. I also don't know if there is somehow already a built-in mechanism for connection timeouts in HTTPUrlConnection.

```
public static String openUrl(String url, String method, Bundle params)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    // random string as boundary for multi-part http post
    String strBoundary = "3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f";
    String endLine = "\r\n";

    OutputStream os;

    if (method.equals("GET")) {
        url = url + "?" + encodeUrl(params);
    }
    Log.d("Facebook-Util", method + " URL: " + url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
            .openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", System.getProperties()
            .getProperty("http.agent") + " FacebookAndroidSDK");
    if (!method.equals("GET")) {
        Bundle dataparams = new Bundle();
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            if (params.getByteArray(key) != null) {
                dataparams.putByteArray(key, params.getByteArray(key));
            }
        }

        // use method override
        if (!params.containsKey("method")) {
            params.putString("method", method);
        }

        if (params.containsKey("access_token")) {
            String decoded_token = URLDecoder.decode(params
                    .getString("access_token"));
            params.putString("access_token", decoded_token);
        }

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + strBoundary);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.connect();
        os = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        os.write(("--" + strBoundary + endLine).getBytes());
        os.write((encodePostBody(params, strBoundary)).getBytes());
        os.write((endLine + "--" + strBoundary + endLine).getBytes());

        if (!dataparams.isEmpty()) {

            for (String key : dataparams.keySet()) {
                os.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\""
                        + key + "\"" + endLine).getBytes());
                os.write(("Content-Type: content/unknown" + endLine + endLine)
                        .getBytes());
                os.write(dataparams.getByteArray(key));
                os.write((endLine + "--" + strBoundary + endLine)
                        .getBytes());

            }
        }
        os.flush();
    }

    String response = "";
    try {
        response = read(conn.getInputStream());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Error Stream contains JSON that we can parse to a FB error
        response = read(conn.getErrorStream());
    }
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation says:

```
httpConn.setConnectTimeout(HTTP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
httpConn.setReadTimeout(HTTP_READ_TIMEOUT);
```

see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int)

Comment: Thanks. Having trouble with this. I put the above lines in immediately before conn.connect(), and I set the timeouts to 1 to test it, but I'm still not getting a SocketTimeoutException. Which methods would actually throw that exception? The documentation for connect() and getInputStream() don't mention it.

Comment: Found this on the Java 1.5 documentation under setConnectTimeout(): "Some non-standard implmentation of this method may ignore the specified timeout. To see the connect timeout set, please call getConnectTimeout()."  When I pause in debug mode after setting the timeout, the member variables for the timeouts in the connection instance are zero, but calling getConnectTimeout() returns my value. Don't understand what's going on here.

Comment: After trying it several times, I had one instance where I did get the timeout exception. Surely it's not connecting and reading within 2ms!!?? When I switch off wifi and rely on 3G, it happens every time. Never realized a connection could happen that quickly.

Comment: I haven't had such issues reported in a widely used Android app. You do know we're talking about millisecond timeouts here?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an issue. I plan to set my timeouts at around 60000ms, but I set it to 1ms to test it.  Half the time, the connection goes through and I get the full response from Facebook. But I don't know for sure if that means that 1ms is enough time for my connection to actually open. Seems like too little time to be possible, but I'm new to web development.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if timeouts are sanitized somewhere along the path. A 1 ms timeout is indeed too short for anything remote to succeed. Another issue with such a short timeout is that you don't know the mechanism behind it. It might very well be that timeouts are checked once every X ms, with X in the range of 10-100. I'm 99% sure that you setting the timeout to 1 ms will not make Android issue a `select()` or `poll()` system call with a 1 ms timeout.